# Bazel platform-specific C++ defines

Tags: c++, bazel

How should one include a platform-specific flag in bazel?

Say we have a cross-platform library that we want to change defines on.

Can we do something like:

```
defines = ["FEATURE_A"]
if somehow_detect_the_platform == 'ios':
    defines.extend("FEATURE_B")

cc_library(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = ["foo.cc"],
    defines = defines,
    hdrs = ["foo.h"],
)
```

Also note that this concept can apply to other things like includes, cflags, sources, headers, etc.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 options. First is using [select function](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/functions.html#select). With select you can conditionally set the value of an attribute depending on the current configuration.

Second option is to tweak the [CROSSTOOL](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/wiki/About-the-CROSSTOOL) configuration file, put a specific [feature](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/main/protobuf/crosstool_config.proto#L182) that would emit different flags depending on the toolchain. Then you can enable that feature in your cc_library in [features](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/common-definitions.html#common.features) attribute.

First option is simpler, the second one is more robust and more encapsulated.